# Select events only when there are slots available

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to select only the events that have slots available. The maximum slots are defined by a column on my events table, while slots taken up are counted from the invitations table. Problem is, the invitation counting is applying to all events instead applying per event ID, and members shown per event is just all invited users that have been accepted to anything.

Edit: How to pass a variable through a called function on the view? I think if I can pass eventID into my countMembers function, then that could fix the counting.

Edit2: Solved. Just move the queries into their own functions and pass the id as a parameter.

Selecting Events

```
      $eventCompetition=DB::table('events')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=' , 'events.user_id')
            ->leftjoin('invitations','invitations.event_id', '=', 'events.eventID')
            ->where('events.eventType','=', 'Competition')
            ->where('events.eventStatus','=', 'UPCOMING')
            ->where('events.eventIsArchived','=', '0')
            ->where('events.user_id','!=',Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('events.eventSlots','>', 
                (DB::table('invitations')
                ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'invitations.sender_id')
                ->leftjoin('events', 'events.eventID', '=', 'invitations.event_id')
                ->whereColumn('invitations.event_id','events.eventID')
                ->where('invitations.status','=','ACCEPTED')
                ->count())
            )
            ->orderBy('events.eventDateStart','DESC')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Viewing Members

```
        $members=DB::table('invitations')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'invitations.sender_id')
            ->leftjoin('events', 'events.eventID', '=', 'invitations.event_id')
            ->whereColumn('invitations.event_id','events.eventID')
            ->where('invitations.status','=','ACCEPTED')
            ->orderBy('users.fName')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Counting Members

```
    public static function countMembers()
    {
        //
        $members=DB::table('invitations')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'invitations.sender_id')
            ->leftjoin('events', 'events.eventID', '=', 'invitations.event_id')
            ->whereColumn('invitations.event_id','events.eventID')
            ->where('invitations.status','=','ACCEPTED')
            ->count();

        return $members;
    }
```

View

```
@foreach($eventCompetition as $event)
<form action = "/joinEvent/{{$event->eventID}}" method = "post">
<div id="viewEvent{{$event->eventID}}" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-login">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-white"style="background-color: #018BB5">        
            <h3 class="modal-title" style="color:black;"><strong>Event Info</strong></h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><h1>&times;</h1></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body form-row col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-striped" style="color:black;">
                <thead>
                    <input type="hidden" id="receive" name="receive" value="{{$event->user_id}}">
                    @csrf
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Event Name:</th>
                        <td>{{$event->eventName}}</td>              
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Event Type:</th>
                        <td>{{$event->eventType}}</td>              
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Max Slots:</th>
                        <td>{{$event->eventSlots}}</td>              
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Address:</th>
                        <td>{{$event->eventAddress}}</td>              
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Sport:</th>
                        <td>{{$event->eventSport}}</td>              
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Date:</th>
                        <td><?php echo Carbon::parse($event->eventDateStart)->format('d F Y h:i:s A'); ?> <br>to <br><?php echo Carbon::parse($event->eventDateEnd)->format('d F Y h:i:s A'); ?></td>              
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Details:</th>
                        <td>{{$event->eventDetails}}</td>              
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Members (<?php echo EventController::countMembers(); ?>/{{$event->eventSlots}}):</th>
                        <td>
                            @foreach($members as $member)
                                <?php
                                    echo "<br>$member->fName $member->mName $member->lName";
                                ?>
                            @endforeach
                        </td>              
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <?php
                if($event->sender_id != Auth::user()->id){
                    echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg text-white' data-toggle='modal'  data-target='#exampleModal$event->eventID'><strong>Send Join Request</strong></button>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>  
</form>
@endforeach
```

Comment: warning, PHP isn't my specialty, but `->whereColumn('invitations.event_id','events.eventID')` looks like an "implied inner join", i.e. you no longer have a left join returning empty slots because those 2 columns must be equal. Sorry if this is misleading. To retain the left join you need to allow for NULLs from the left joined table.

Comment: I fixed the problem. To avoid using the whereColumn, I just replaced the where('eventSlots'... portion of the code by passing an $id parameter on the countMembers function and using that as my comparison to the eventSlots. For viewing the members, I just turned the query into its own function with an $id parameter as well. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I suggest you provide a proper answer and select that. SO encourages answering one's own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, here's my solution

Replaced the nested query with a static function

Select Event

```
$eventCompetition=DB::table('events')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=' , 'events.user_id')
            ->leftjoin('invitations','invitations.event_id', '=', 'events.eventID')
            ->where('events.eventType','=', 'Competition')
            ->where('events.eventStatus','=', 'UPCOMING')
            ->where('events.eventIsArchived','=', '0')
            ->where('events.user_id','!=',Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('events.eventSlots','>', $this->countMembers('event.eventID'))
            ->orderBy('events.eventDateStart','DESC')
            ->distinct()
            ->paginate(10);
```

Count and View Members

```
    public static function countMembers($id)
    {
        //
        $members=DB::table('invitations')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'invitations.sender_id')
            ->leftjoin('events', 'events.eventID', '=', 'invitations.event_id')
            ->where('invitations.event_id','=', $id)
            ->where('invitations.status','=','ACCEPTED')
            ->count();

        return $members;
    }

    public static function getMembers($id)
    {
        //
        $members=DB::table('invitations')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'invitations.sender_id')
            ->leftjoin('events', 'events.eventID', '=', 'invitations.event_id')
            ->where('invitations.event_id','=',$id)
            ->where('invitations.status','=','ACCEPTED')
            ->orderBy('users.fName')
            ->get();

        return $members;
    }
```

View

```
@foreach($eventTraining as $event)
<form action = "/joinEvent/{{$event->eventID}}" method = "post">
<div id="viewEvent{{$event->eventID}}" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-login">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header text-white"style="background-color: #018BB5">        
                            <h3 class="modal-title" style="color:black;"><strong>Event Info</strong></h3>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><h1>&times;</h1></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body form-row col-md-12">
                                    <table class="table table-striped" style="color:black;">
                                            <thead>
                                                <input type="hidden" id="receive" name="receive" value="{{$event->user_id}}">
                                                @csrf
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <th scope="row">Event Name:</th>
                                                            <td>{{$event->eventName}}</td>              
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <th scope="row">Event Type:</th>
                                                            <td>{{$event->eventType}}</td>              
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <th scope="row">Max Slots:</th>
                                                            <td>{{$event->eventSlots}}</td>              
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <th scope="row">Address:</th>
                                                            <td>{{$event->eventAddress}}</td>              
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <th scope="row">Sport:</th>
                                                            <td>{{$event->eventSport}}</td>              
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <th scope="row">Date:</th>
                                                            <td><?php echo Carbon::parse($event->eventDateStart)->format('d F Y h:i:s A'); ?> <br>to <br><?php echo Carbon::parse($event->eventDateEnd)->format('d F Y h:i:s A'); ?></td>              
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <th scope="row">Details:</th>
                                                            <td>{{$event->eventDetails}}</td>              
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <th scope="row">Members (<?php echo EventController::countMembers($event->eventID); ?>/{{$event->eventSlots}}):</th>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <?php
                                                                    $members = EventController::getMembers($event->eventID);
                                                                    foreach($members as $member):
                                                                        echo $member->fName." ".$member->mName." ".$member->lName;
                                                                    endforeach
                                                                ?>
                                                            </td>              
                                                    </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                    </table>
                                    <?php
                                        if($event->sender_id != Auth::user()->id){
                                            echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg text-white' data-toggle='modal'  data-target='#exampleModal$event->eventID'><strong>Send Join Request</strong></button>";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                            </div>                
                    </div>
            </div>    
        </div>  
    </form>
 @endforeach
```